# Parameter specified as non-null is null: parameter projection Content Provider Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I am trying to query content provider from Kotlin file. Please see the code below:

```
var URI = Uri.parse("content://myprovider")
var nameUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(URI, "name")
cursor = contentResolver.query(nameUri, null, null, null, null)
```

When I run this code, I am getting below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter projection
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:418)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:802)
```

Now, when I checked the query method signature in ContentResolver class, this is what it is

```
public final @Nullable Cursor query(@RequiresPermission.Read @NonNull Uri uri,
        @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection,
        @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder)
```

As you can see, everything apart from Uri can be Nullable, so technically it should not throw this error.

Also, I tried giving projection but then it threw an error for selectionArgs.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

***Note:*** Neither contentResolver not nameUri is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this

```
override fun query(uri: Uri, projection: Array<String>?, selection: String?,
               selectionArgs: Array<String>?, sortOrder: String?): Cursor? {

//ur code

return cursor
}
```

[refer to this link](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Kotlin_Android_Content_Provider_Tutorial)

Comment: in which class MyContentProvider?

Comment: while you extent ContentProvider in your class, this method should be overridden. `class MyContentProvider : ContentProvider()`

Comment: you are a life saver, man! Thanks a lot. Accepted the answer.

Comment: in my case, I removed "?" from projection so adding it again fixed my problem.